# adding hidden data to text fields in html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4

suppose i have a form with a table containing text boxes:

- The columns are decided by user decisions earlier in the form. (the pure, unhidden form will be about 70 columns wide, usually reduced to about 5 columns)
- The rows can be added and deleted by the user clicking clicking an "add_row" and a "delete_row", respectively

what i am wanting to do is be able to add hidden data to the text fields via html or Javascript so i can establish which column a certain input corresponds to in the rails controller when iterating through the table rows

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script to get value of text box

```
var x = $("#textBox1").val();
```

now add a hidden data to x ie:

```
x = x + ":col1";
```

hope this helps